# How do i get shipping method of current Store : Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am creating functionality to get Shipping methods enabled for selected store.

Currently I am using below code to get Shipping details :

```
$methods = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getActiveCarriers();
$shipMethods = array();

foreach ($methods as $shippigCode=>$shippingModel) 
{

    $shippingTitle = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$shippigCode.'/title');
    $shippingPrice = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$shippigCode.'/price');
    $shippingLabel = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$shippigCode.'/label');
    $shipMethods[]=array('Shipping Type' => $shippigCode, 'title'=> $shippingTitle, 'price'=> $shippingPrice);


}
print_r($shipMethods);
```

I only get config details of the default store.

My question is : **How do i get shipping methods of selected store?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default the value is null in getActiveCarriers

`getActiveCarriers($store = null)`

So you can pass the store as a parameter. 
You can get the current store with

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId()
```

So the function you will use is

```
Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getActiveCarriers(Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId())
```